# How do I kit products without options?

Tags: products-management

How do I create a product kit (multiple simple products) without any options? If I crate a bundle it gives the user options and it creates an extra step during admin checkout.

Is there anything out there to assemble kits without options?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look @ [Magento - Wiki - Product Types](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/catalog_product/producttype)

**Grouped products** allow you to create a new product using one or more existing products in your store. For instance, let’s assume you have a “Barrack Obama Action Figure” and a “George W Bush Action Figure” already in your store and you wanted to sell them as a bundle. You would simply create a new Grouped Product (let’s call it “Obama + Bush (Get Both and Spend Twice as Much!)”, then add both action figures to the group via the “Associated Products” tab.

Note: Unfortunately, you are not able to set a special “group” price directly from the product page. To offer a discount for buying items together, you will need to create a new Shopping Cart Price Rule.

Comment: Please remember to accept my answer if it solve your issue. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this using a Bundle Item, but was unable to get rid of the extra click to "configure" before "add to cart"

My requirements were to create a bundle of other SKU's where the user does not have any options to modify, and the price was fixed with a $5 discount

So go into the admin and add a new bundle product

Under "Bundle Items" Add an option for each product that you want in the kit.
Set required to true
Set Input type to Radio button
Add one product to the option
Set the product as the default
Set your default quantity to what you want and user defined = false

See 
[Admin setup](https://nimbus.everhelper.me/client/notes/share/1011068/txb2qb8q6qw0rlea2pv9) screenshot

For the price you just need to calculate your percentage accordingly.  My price was $30 and I want a $5 discount so the percent is 83.33

[Here's what it came out with in the front end](https://nimbus.everhelper.me/client/notes/share/1011072/5grdn1dv4pitdsoixsdf)

Only downsides are again the extra click to configure and some extra text output on the frontend.  functionally it works as needed.